# selecting multiple tables in mysql and combine the results

Tags: mysql, sql

Our team use mysql as the database. Due to the large amount of data. we split the original database and table to multiple ones through some specific field value.

For example, we have database Info and table `t_roll_log` in Info. The definition of `t_roll_log` might be some thing like

```
create table `t_roll_log`(
`F_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`F_name`    varchar(256) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY(`F_user_id`)
)ENGINE=InnDB
```

we split the original database into 100 ones, each contains 10 tables using F_user_id's last three digit. For example `F_user_id=1020` record will be in `Info_02.t_roll_log_02_0` while `F_user_id=7721` record will be in `Info_72.t_roll_log_72_1`.

In such case, we reduced the pressure of the table when there is a lot of DB read/write. but the question is, can I easily fetch results from this 1000 tables without using external scripts (like PHP or Python)?

For example, in mysql client, perhaps I want to count total record numbers in t_roll_log, I'm looking for some thing like this

```
select count(*) from Info_{00~99}.t_roll_log_{00~99}_{0~9} ;
```

Does mysql support similar grammar or is there any For loop syntax in mysql?

thank you.

Comment: why you not use partitioning?

Comment: Have you looked into using `UNION` tables?

Comment: thank you, @AbsoluteƵERØ, this is link is rather helpful.